How to recieve MS Teams created announcements to my webapp python (django)
In my MS teams I create an announcement, the announcement I created will be sent to my webapp python django then stored into my database, is this possible?
I've been doing some research and some ways on how to tackle this problem majority of the stuffs ive discover is mostly how to post messages in MS Teams through the connectors.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use Microsoft Teams connectors to send messages from Teams to your web application, where you can then process and store the announcements in your database. With Outgoing Webhooks, you can send text messages from a channel to a web service. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors#outgoing-webhooks
